# Determine # of pages from Total and PerPage values

Tags: c#, pagination

What is the most elegant way (in C#) of determining how many pages of data you have given:

a.) Total Records
b.) Records Per page.

Currently what I have is working, but it's using if/else to check if the value is than the total (1 page) or more, and then has to truncate the decimal place, perform a mod operation and add 1 more if there was a trailing decimal.

I'm sure there's a Math function that does alot of this for me and isn't so ugly.

Thanks.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
int pages = ((totalRecords-1) / recordsPerPage)+1
```

Assuming `totalRecords` and `recordsPerPage` are ints. If they're doubles (why are they doubles?) you'll need to convert them to ints or longs first, because this relies on integer division to work.

Wrap it in a function so that you don't have to repeat the calculation everywhere in your code base. Just set it up once in a function like this:

```
public int countPages(int totalRecords, int recordsPerPage) {
  return ((totalRecords-1) / recordsPerPage)+1;
}
```

If `totalRecords` can be zero, you can just add a special case for it in the function easily:

```
public int countPages(int totalRecords, int recordsPerPage) {
  if (totalRecords == 0) { return 1; }
  return ((totalRecords-1) / recordsPerPage)+1;
}
```

Comment: `if (totalRecords <= recordsPerPage) { return 1; }`

Comment: No need to test for the case where `totalRecords == 0` because `-1` divided by `recordsPerPage` gets rounded to `0` as long as `recordsPerPage` is greater than `1`, which is usually the case.

Answer (score 0):

```
int pages = 1 + (totalRecords + 1) / (recordsPerPage + 1)
```

Comment: That doesn't work if both totalRecords and recordsPerPage are the same. It will output 2 instead of the correct 1. You shouldn't be adding one to the numerator, just the denominator.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with this approach:

```
public int countPages(int totalRecords, int recordsPerPage) {  
    if (totalRecords == 0) { return 1; }  return ((totalRecords-1) / recordsPerPage)+1;
}
```

if totalRecords is 1 results in divide by 0. Need an extra if statement.

Here is my rewrite. .NET tends to use -1 when no result is possible on an int return. So reuse this convention.

```
public int countPages(int totalRecords, int recordsPerPage)
{ 

//insert as many paranthesies and tabs as makes you happy.
if(totalRecords == 0) return -1;
return (totalRecords % recordsPerPage) == 0? 
(totalRecords/recordsPerPage) 
: (totalRecords/recordsPerPage) + 1; 

}
```

Comment: It doesn't result in a divide-by-0 error. That would only be possible of `recordsPerPage` were 0.

Answer (score -1):

```
int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((double)totalRecords/recordsPerPage);
```

Comment: I can just imagine the computer deciding that 50/25 = 2.0000000000096 or some such nonsense.